# A Subset of Abelian group with order of elements either $1\ or\ even$ is not subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

From Abstract Algebra By Gallian:

Let $G$ be an Abelian group and $H=\{x\in G | |x|=1\ or\ even\}$.Give an example to show that $H$ need not be a subgroup of $G$.

$e\in H,\ so H\neq \phi$

Suppose $a,b\neq e$ such that $a,b\in H$ since $ab=ba,o(ab)=lcm(o(a),o(b))$.But since $o(a)\ and\ o(b)$ both are even ,its lcm,$lcm(o(a),o(b))$ must also be even.So $ab \in H$

And since $a\ and\ a^{-1}$ have same order implies for $a\in H,a^{-1}\in H$.Which imply $H$ is always a subgroup.
So,why they are saying $H$ need not be a subgroup ?
Am I wrong somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think that $o(ab) = \mathrm{lcm}(o(a), o(b))$? Consider for example the case that $b = a^{-1}$ (but $a \neq e$).

Comment: Actually I thought,for $ab=ba,o(ab)=lcm(o(a),o(a))$.Now I got I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is cyclic of order $6$, and $a$ generates $G$, what are the orders of $a$ and $a^2$?